# What type of qWidget is the qtcreator design mode?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwidget

I have seen toolBox widget in Qt, but I am looking for something similar to qtCreator design mode (picture below), which has Filter (search by name) and open/close parts. Is there any widget similar to that or is it customized/inherited widget?

[image]

Comment: you need to "upgrade" toolBox. for example ,put qlineedit for filter and program it( connect signals, etc...)

Comment: You can have a look in the qtcreator source `git clone --recursive https://code.qt.io/qt-creator/qt-creator.git`

Answer (score 0):

That's the `WidgetBox` or `WidgetBoxTreeWidget`, available in the Designer source code in the `qttools` repository:

https://github.com/qt/qttools/tree/dev/src/designer/src/components/widgetbox